# Calling a Get method in Web API with attribute routing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

My `WebApi.config` looks like this:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

which means it is `configured to support both attribute based routing and conventional routing`.

And the sample controller created:

```
[RoutePrefix("v1")]
public class Values1Controller : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };

    }

    [Route("products")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

When I invoke http://localhost.domain/api/values1/v1/ the response is `value1, value2`

But, when I try to invoke http://localhost.domain/api/values1/v1/products/1 (notice the `products` attribute route on the `public string Get(int id)` method, the break point is not hit.

In other words, how to call the `public string Get(int id)` method with the attribute routing `Route(products)` on top of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `/v1/products?id=10` to hit the action `public string Get(int id)` or change your route template to be `[Route("products/{id}")]` to make request like `/v1/products/10`

Note that attributed controllers/actions cannot be reached by requests which match conventional routes, so that means you *cannot* do something like `api/values/1` to reach `public string Get(int id)` action

Comment: Great. Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot

Comment: `http://localhost:portNum/v1/products?id=10` hits the breakpoint when the routing attribute is [Route("products")]. `http://localhost:portNum/v1/products/10` hits the breakpoint when the routing attribute is [Route("products/{id}")]. Nice explanation @Kiran. Thanks.